# Add a back button in activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, audio, android-activity

Good morning, Guys I have a code that plays an audio when the activity starts it performs a welcome greeting, however when I go to other activities and return to the main menu the audio is played again I would like to notice that when I use the back action bar button I don't have this problem, but I need to use a button in the fragment or activity, I can't have an action bar in my app

Code to Play audio:

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MediaPlayer play= MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.audioboatarde);
                play.start();
            }
        }, 1000);
```

Code button on fragment:

```
button = view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
             startActivity(intent1);
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop your media playback when you leave the activity in `onPause` of the Activity

```
@Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        play.stop();
    }
```

And you don't need to restart the previous activity on click of the button in the second activity, you just need to call `onBackPressed()` to go to the previous activity.

```
button = view.findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

       onBackPressed();
    }

});
```

Comment: I used this method in my activity and it worked, thank you very much, but this method cannot be applied directly to a fragment, I tried but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

This is my second answer.

In the case you have to relauch the first activity(if it is destroyed) from the second one, 
you can also use `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)`
to save the audio played state in the activity.

In the first activity

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
   outState.putBoolean("isPlayed",true);
   super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

In `onCreate()` of the first activity

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstaceState.getBoolean("isPlayed") == false) {
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MediaPlayer play=  MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.audioboatarde);
                play.start();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Later on, you can relaunch the first activity from the second activity.

```
button = view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
             startActivity(intent1);
        }

    });
```

Dont forget to stop the audio playback in the first activity.

```
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        play.stop();
    }
```